# Stats updates on area51

Tags: discussion, area51, site-statistics

Hi,

I want to know how often are the stats on [are51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning) page of judaism.stackexchange are updated.
I have a feeling that the numbers about questions per day are not correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67964/how-often-are-the-progress-pages-updated-on-area-51/68157#68157):

> The progress/stats pages on Area 51 are updated hourly.

Something to note, though: the progress is averaged over a period of time (that's how we can get fractions of questions). So, while I don't know the exact details of the algorithms, it could be earlier days are "pulling" it down.